# Числовая клавиатура для сенсорного экрана WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, терминал

Разрабатываю приложение WPF, которое будет выполняться на сенсорных устройствах терминалов на Windows 10. Я никогда не работал с сенсорными устройствами и у меня нет сенсорного устройства на Windows.

Надо сделать ввод исключительно чисел в текстовые поля. Есть ли встроенные средства для этого или придётся прямо в окно добавлять кнопки от 0 до 9?

Comment: Стандартное средство - приложение "Экранная клавиатура" (osk.exe). Но если нужны только цифровые кнопки, то придется свое делать

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37774400/2110496

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/abeffb18-d291-4b05-8ca2-3a9b03d28560/wpf-c-windows-popup-touch-keyboard-show-numeric-keypad-by-default?forum=wpf - возможно в инпут надо добавить `InputScope="Number"`

Comment: @Grundy Это не решает полностью проблему, но сильно улучшает ввод, поэтому благодарю. Только для того, чтобы это увидеть надо переключить Windows 10 в Tablet Mode. Также для вызова клавиатуры приходится вручную нажимать её значок на панели задач справа.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, тут не могу ничего сказать :-) возможно на самом устройстве нужная клавиатура будет показываться автоматически :)

Comment: Я бы написал свой UserControl, во-первых, он простой, а во-вторых, у вас отпадает необходимость вадидации ввода (что очень серьёзное преимущество)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Типа унаследоваться от `TextBox` и обработать `PreviewTextInput`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, нет, просто написать клавиатуру в виде отдельного UserControl, у которого выставить наружу свойство зависимости Text (или int Value, если хотите). В VM просто привязываетесь к этому свойству, а вывод можно сделать вообще в TextBlock, чтобы пользователь туда точно ничего не ввел другим путем

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это не так и просто будет сделать, как мне кажется. Хотя бы потому что есть нюансы. К примеру, если текстовое поле снизу окна, то нужно клавиатуру показать над текстовым полем.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ага, тогда делаете текстовое поле с клавиатурой в одном контроле, клавиатура всегда ниже поля ввода. По-умолчанию клавиатура скрыта, при получении контролом фокуса клавиатура становится видимой, а панель прокручивается так, чтобы вся клавиатура была видна. Думаю, не очень сложно это будет.